# Closest point to another point on a hypersphere

Tags: algorithm, performance, computational-geometry

I have n (about 10^5) points on a hypersphere of dimension m (between 10^4 to 10^6).

I am going to make a bunch of queries of the form "given a point p, find the closest of the n points to p". I'll make about n of these queries.

(Not sure if the hypersphere fact helps at all.)

The simple naive algorithm to solve this is, for each query, to compare p to all other n points. Doing this n times ends up with a runtime of O(n^2 m), which is far too big for me to be able to compute.

Is there a more efficient algorithm I can use? If I could get it to O(nm) with some log factors that'd be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not.  Having many dimensions makes efficient indexing extremely hard.  That is why people look for opportunities to reduce the number of dimensions to something manageable.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction for more.

Answer (score 0):

Divide your space up into hypercubes -- call these cells -- with edge size chosen so that on average you'll have one point per cube. You'll want a map from hypercells to the set of points they contain.

Then, given a point, check its hypercell for other points. If it is empty, look at the adjacent hypercells (I'd recommend a literal hypercube of hypercells for simplicity rather than some approximation to a hypersphere built out of hypercells). Check that for other points. Keep repeating until you get a point. Assuming your points are randomly distributed, odds are high that you'll find a second point within 1-2 expansions.

Once you find a point, check all hypercells that could possibly contain a closer point. This is possible because the point you find may be in a corner, but there's some closer point outside of the hypercube containing all the hypercells you've inspected so far.

Comment: This approach works great in 2-3 dimensions.  But not so great in 10,000 since the odds are that every point winds up in an incomparable hypercube and you have to look at each point in the end anyways.